# Java Cookie auto manager

Tags: java, cookies

I'm new to Java. And I have some troubles with Java's  Cookies.
Let me put it.

I just want to post json(paras like username and password) to a server using API. If I have login, I can request other datas using API, but I have to provide information using cookies.
I just want to get some methods like **Python's Cookiejar** which can manager cookies automatically.

So,I can post the username and password to the http server using some tools like cookiejar firstly.Then I can get other data using the cookies by requesting http API.

could you help me?

Comment: I think you are looking for HttpSession. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Comment: ok,Thanks! I do not HttpSession.